# Merging XML and XSD then apply XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I have a xml file which is supposed to hold only data and a xsd file which is for both validation and construction of the page. In other words I apply xsl to xsd but at the same time I get the values of fields from xml(At least this is wanted from me).

Applying xsl to xsd is not a problem. But it only works when I call "sample.xsd" file from browser as normal and this is not something I want to. I want to call "sample.xml".And it creates a html output which is constructed according to xsd file and values from xml.

More explanation:

Think I have a XML file. And in it XSLT and XSD files are defined. When I call this XML file from browser, I want to apply styles-let me say create html output (like: creating input fields according to predefined nodes in this XSD file)- to XSD file and then put values to these fields from XML file. At the end it comes to this: I want to apply XSLT to both XML(to read data) and XSD(to create output). Is it possible?

Comment: Sorry, your question isn't clear enough. Please be more precise about what you are doing (for example, are you doing an XSLT transformation in the browser, if so, how, and with which browser); what exactly happened, and what did you want to happen?

Comment: @Michael Kay I updated the question. I hope I could explain my problem more

Comment: As it is, this incomprehensible question won't help anyone.

Comment: I think he is asking how he can use XML, XSD and XSL to create a more human-readable document.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever I have found something to solve it.

With proper namespaces, you can use document() function inside XSLT file and apply xpath -or whatever it is- on it, like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="document('sample.xsd')/xs:schema/xs:complexType[@name='fieldtype']/xs:choice/child::*">
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

And still you can use xml file for other situations. I hope this helps someone